# How to calculate bandwidth usage for RDP

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, bandwidth, resource-monitor

I'm looking to calculate the actual amount of data sent and received for RDP for a given session. Just trying to figure out, given a typical hour or day of usage, how much bandwidth I would use if I was on a capped data plan.

I've read plenty of wildly different numbers about how much is used by RDP on average, from 2kbps to 100. And I know it varies depending on what you're doing, which is why I want to calculate it myself for what I'd be doing.

Using Resource Monitor, I can see an average, but from what I can tell, its numbers are average over a short time - I want a much longer timeframe to account for normal daily activity, so I want to calculate it myself with real numbers.

Is there any way to use Resource Monitor, or any other relatively simple tool, to watch a given process or port and get a cumulative send and receive byte count over a reasonably long period of time?

Comment: The simplest way.  Download a bandwidth monitor.  Use RDP like normal for a 24 hour period, then extrapolate the usage for a day.

Comment: @Ramhound Any recommendations? I'm not getting a warm and fuzzy feeling from the websites I'm seeing.

Comment: @JoeEnos http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/d/9/4d9ae285-3431-4335-a86e-969e7a146d1b/RDP_Performance_WhitePaper.docx RDP 7 vs 6 http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/6/8/56878CBB-68E1-4FA9-B609-D06CC4A25715/Remote%20Desktop%20Protocol%20Performance%20Improvements%20in%20Windows%20Server%202008%20R2%20and%20Windows%207.doc

Comment: @STTR Thanks, I saw that - it's part of why I want to measure myself - there's a huge range of data there, and I couldn't tell you off the top of my head what percentage of my time is "scrolling", or what the difference between a regular and executive PowerPoint is. Plus both docs are pretty old, so who knows how reliable this is with today's operating systems.

Comment: @JoeEnos - Use the tool of your choice to do my suggestion.

Comment: @JoeEnos Protocol and its implementation have not changed much. The only traffic decreased for 32 bit color version 7. If you have version 8 and RemoteFX, then the codec compresses 2 times better for some cases than for RDP 7. Accordingly, to evaluate the capacity of better Based RDP 6, due for a possible performance decrease codec RemoteFX. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2012/08/06/remotefx-adaptive-graphics-in-windows-server-2012-and-windows-8.aspx